# Linking Google Analytics 4 to Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I am trying to link GA4 to a bigquery project. I already have universal analytics data being exported into the bigquery project. Can I also link GA4 to the same bigquery project?

Thanks,

Sriram

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can connect a GA4 property to export to the same GCP project as a GA3 property. You'll need to set up your data stream, then go into the admin panel of your GA4 property and look under "Product links" for "BigQuery Links":

[image]

In this screen you can select the data stream you want to sync, the BigQuery project you want to send it too and the frequency of data export.